# Problem with classification, POST to classifications results in error

Tags: weaviate

If I try to start a classification I receive the error message:

`"message": "invalid classification: basedOnProperties: property 'title' must be of type 'text'"`

I am running 0.22.0

The property is of the type string, I didn't know of types that are text. Is this right?

The query I have POST to /v1/classifications was:

```
{ 
    "class": "ClassContainingTitle", 
    "classifyProperties": ["inOtherclass"], 
    "basedOnProperties": ["title"], 
    "type": "contextual" 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `basedOnProperties` should indeed be op dataType text, like the error message mentions. (This is required for the vectorization of the field for the classification).

The best thing to do is this to mention a property that has the correct dataType (`text`). Is there is none in this class yet, you could change the field of this property from `string` to `text` in the schema.

How to start this classification is also reflected in the documentation https://www.semi.technology/documentation/weaviate/current/features/contextual-classification.html#how-to-use.

Comment: regarding the documentation I have created an issue on Github, it states `/v1/classification` which is incorrect, it should be `/v1/classifications`

Comment: Thanks @MauricedeJong, this is resolved and will be part of the next website release.